# Traverse a value if the property changes name every time

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

given this example found on JSON site,
in my case i'm using an API where I have a json where the property name "**glossary**", changes for every request... I mean if you search "**glossary**" the first property is **glossary**, if you search "**apple**" is gonna be **apple** and so on...

xml was easier to traverse...but i dont know how to do it in JSON
i dont know how to get the value **title** if **glossary** changes...

using javascript/jquery i tried something like data[0].title...but doesnt work

```
{
        "glossary": {
            "title": "example glossary",
            "GlossDiv": {
                "title": "S",
                "GlossList": {
                    "GlossEntry": {
                        "ID": "SGML",
                        "SortAs": "SGML",
                        "GlossTerm": "Standard Generalized Markup Language",
                        "Acronym": "SGML",
                        "Abbrev": "ISO 8879:1986",
                        "GlossDef": {
                            "para": "A meta-markup language, used to create markup languages such as DocBook.",
                            "GlossSeeAlso": ["GML", "XML"]
                        },
                        "GlossSee": "markup"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: What are the rules for finding title? Just iterate over (and skip) the top-level?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for (property_name in some_object) {
    some_object[property_name]...
}
```

Comment: Without a `hasOwnProperty` check this may also traverse properties in `some_object`'s prototype chain.

Answer (score 0):

Try iterating over all properties inside your json object

```
var json = ...;

for (var i in json) {
    if (json.hasOwnProperty(i)) {
        var elem = json[i];
        // handle element here
    }
}
```

hasOwnProperty ensures that you don't get properties added by changing the object prototype.

Answer (score 0):

If you're interested in returning the first and only property of the object, this should do the trick:

```
function getChild(obj){
    var prop;
    for(prop in obj){
        if(Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(obj,prop)){
            return obj[prop];
        }
    }
}

var json={glossary:{...}};

var child = getProp(json); // child should now contain the glossary object
```

It should be noted that in cases where there are multiple properties in the json object there can be no guarantee of which child will be returned, as the for..in traversal has no specific order.